# Make record truly immutable even a field is a collection

Tags: java, java-record

The naive approach to have a record field that is a collection leads to mutable records, and I think that's something we don't want.

Do people generally ignore this aspect, or does one try hard to make the record truly immutable?

If the latter, what would one do?

The naive approach would be `record Foo(List<String> bar) { }`, and I guess people can do `foo.bar().add(...)` and similar things to mutate this “immutable” record.

The record constructor could clone the list, then make it unmodifiable, would that be sufficient?

```java
record Foo(List<String> bar) {
    Foo {
        bar = new ArrayList<>(bar);
        bar = Collections.unmodifiableList(bar);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this leads to some other way where `foo.bar()` ends up being mutable after all.

All of the above can only work because `String` is immutable, I understand that we need to make sure that a record is only constructed of immutable things.

Comment: There are immutable collection types. [Example](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)

Comment: Use `List.copyOf(..)` instead of `new ArrayList(..)`, and remove the use of `unmodifiableList`.

Comment: In later JDKs another benefit of `List.copyOf(bar)` is that the list won't be copied if the list is known to be immutable - say from an earlier `List.copyOf(xyz)`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the state of the list is concerned, this is enough for the record to be immutable. A test that proves it:

```
public class ImmutabilityTests {

  private List<String> initialList;
  private Foo foo;
  private List<String> expectedList;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    this.initialList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    this.foo = new Foo(this.initialList);
    this.expectedList = new ArrayList<>(this.initialList);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRecordListEqualsInitialList() {
    assertEquals(this.expectedList, this.foo.bar(), "Record list does not equal initial list");
  }

  @Test
  public void testChangingInitialListDoesNotAffectRecordList() {
    this.initialList.clear();
    assertEquals(this.expectedList, this.foo.bar(), "Changing initial list should not affect record list");
  }

  @Test
  public void testChangingRecordListThrowsException() {
    assertThrows(UnsupportedOperationException.class, () -> this.foo.bar().clear(), "Record list was not immutable");
  }
}
```

The list in `Foo` is equal to the initial list, changing initial list does not change list in record, and attempting to change list in `Foo` throws exception.

Additionally you can simplify the record constructor, using [`List.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)):

> Returns an unmodifiable List containing the elements of the given Collection, in its iteration order. The given Collection must not be null, and it must not contain any null elements. If the given Collection is subsequently modified, the returned List will not reflect such modifications.

```
public record Foo(List<String> bar) {
  public Foo {
    bar = List.copyOf(bar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is your answer. it creates an immutable list regardless of what are the contents. Even if the instances that you store in the list are of a mutable class. One more trick before you pass your list as a parameter do this:

```
public final ArrayList<MyClass> constantList = Collections.unmodifiableList(origList);
```

This will protect you from someone assigning new list instance to your `constantList`

Comment: The field in a record is already `final` (the assignments to `bar` in the constructor shown in the question are to the constructor parameter, not the field).

Comment: `it creates an immutable list regardless of what are the contents. Even if the instances that you store in the list are of a mutable class.` - this is misleading. You can iterate an unmodifiable list, and mutate the state of each element in it, the most obvious example being calling the setter of a property - `element.setMyProperty(value)`.